# How to change listing language in Magento

Tags: magento, webshop

Who knows where to find the translation files for the price selections (see picture)
I can't change this in the front end inline translation

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Price and other sorting attributes title can be changed in Magento Admin Panel in `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Edit Attribute -> Manage Labels / Options` where you can specify the attribute title for each store view.

There is only one exception... It is `Position` option, that is a hard-coded value in sort by array. But you can change this value by editing locale file `app/locale/[your_locale]/Mage_Catalog.csv`, just search for `Position` text inside of it, and change value in the second column.

Comment: Great! Thanks Ivan. This was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks! saved my day too, I was going to do it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the loop that fill the select box in this file:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
// line 81
...
foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): 
...
```

Here is where the list of available order is set

```
// Line 424
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

From there, you could be able to trace the translation.

Hope this help!

**Update:**

Here the list of sort by is fetched
The value seems to be in the attributes configuration

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
// Line 339 in Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
```

Comment: Hey Yvoyer. Thanks for helping. Only this is not exactly what I was looking for I think. What I mean is where I can translate those words. Now it's Position, name and price. The translation extension key has only translated the word position. I would like to translate Price and name also. Any Idea where to find those words?

Answer (score 2):

There may already be a set of translations for you to download. Start by going to http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations, then click "Select" for your language, then click "Package". Unzip the download into your magento directory and it will place a whole lot of CSV files where they need to go. You can edit these yourself with any spreadsheet program. You might need to clear the cache after importing or adjusting these files.

Comment: Thanks for the link clockwork. Is this different than the translation file from the magento connect key? Any idea in what file i can find it?

Comment: Which extension did you use? It may well have done the same thing for you. Look for the file "app/locale/nl_NL/Mage_Catalog.csv" (might be a different directory in the same area) and try to edit that, if "Price" is not in there you can add a new row yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to edit the database:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` 
SET `frontend_label` = 'Reihenfolge' 
WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` ='position';
```

Here you can change `Reihenfolge` to your preferred text.

Answer (score 0):

For position you can translate in your theme's translate.csv file simply add an entry like so.
    `"Mage_Catalog::Position", "Popular"`

Answer (score 0):

to use the translation, change the template app/design/frontend/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ($_key=='position'): echo $this->__('Position'); else: echo $this->__($_order); endif; ?>
```

And add in [theme]/local/[language]/translate.csv

```
"Position","What you want"
```